# Unable to retrieve an object list within another parent object

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework

I have an object named "loans" with another list of objects named "items" stored within it. I am able to retrieve the other attributes of "loan" through page.ts. However, I am unable to retrieve the "items" object attributes within the "loan" object when I attempt to do it using "loan.items".

Console.log has shown that "items" and all its attributes are within the "loan" object but when I attempt to use "loan.items", it gives back an empty array. I am intending to use a for loop to get each item in "loan.items".

[Here is a screenshot of what console.log(loan) returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9bJk.png)

[Here is a screenshot of what console.log(loan.items) returns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h2PcA.png)

loan.page.ts

```
this.loanService.getAllCurrentOrPastLoans("username", user.email, "current")
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.currentLoans = data;

        for (let loan of this.currentLoans) {
          if (loan.status != "rejected") {
            this.currentLoansNo += 1;
            for (let item of loan.items) {
              this.currentLoansItemNo += item.quantity;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

loan.service.ts

```
getAllCurrentOrPastLoans(whereFilter: string, whereValue: any, currentOrPast: string): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    firebase.firestore().collection('loans').where(whereFilter, '==', whereValue).orderBy('duedate').onSnapshot(collection => {
      let array = [];
      collection.forEach(doc => {
          
        if (currentOrPast == 'current') {
          if (doc.data().status != 'completed') {

            // Add loan into array if there's no error
            try {
              let loan = new Loan(doc.data().username, doc.data().status, doc.data().duedate.toDate(), doc.id);
              array.push(loan);
  
              // Read subcollection '/loans/<autoID>/items'
              let dbItems = firebase.firestore().collection('loans/' + doc.id + '/items');
              dbItems.onSnapshot(itemsCollection => {
                loan.items = []; // Empty array
                itemsCollection.forEach(itemDoc => {
                  let item = new Item(itemDoc.id, itemDoc.data().quantity);
                  loan.items.push(item);
                });
              });
            } catch (error) { }
          }

        } else if (currentOrPast == 'past') {

          if (doc.data().status == 'completed') {

            // Add loan into array if there's no error
            try {
              let loan = new Loan(doc.data().username, doc.data().status, doc.data().duedate.toDate(), doc.id, doc.data().returnstatus);
              array.push(loan);
  
              // Read subcollection '/loans/<autoID>/items'
              let dbItems = firebase.firestore().collection('loans/' + doc.id + '/items');
              dbItems.onSnapshot(itemsCollection => {
                loan.items = []; // Empty array
                itemsCollection.forEach(itemDoc => {
                  let item = new Item(itemDoc.id, itemDoc.data().quantity);
                  loan.items.push(item);
                });
              });
            } catch (error) { }
          }

        }


      });
      observer.next(array);
    });
  });
}
```

Comment: Please add a code reproducable code snppet

Comment: Have you placed the results from your `loan.items` in to a variable or a model?

Comment: I've added the code snippet

Comment: I'm trying to get the total quantity of every item in loan.items

Comment: Can you add `getAllCurrentOrPastLoans` code?

Comment: I've added getAllCurrentOrPastLoans codes

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, it looks like you're passing the full response back as a result but your code doesn't know how to access the nested array.

Start by adding a new variable named:

```
loanItems: any = [];
```

And then modify your code to this:

```
this.loanService.getAllCurrentOrPastLoans("username", user.email, "current")
    .subscribe(data => {
        this.currentLoans = data;
        this.loanItems = data.items;

        for (let loan of this.currentLoans) {
          if (loan.status != "rejected") {
            this.currentLoansNo += 1;
            for (let item of loanItems) {
              this.currentLoansItemNo += item.quantity;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

See if that gives you a result.

Comment: this.loanItems = data.items produces an error message of "this.loanItems is not an iterable" as data returns an array of loans. The array of loan contains all loans and each loan contains an array of items as well. Hence, data.items doesn not seem to return anything.

Comment: Can you access the loan array in console if you comment out the loop and `console.log(this.loanItems)`?

Comment: `console.log(this.loanItems)` shows undefined in the console

Comment: Have you set the variable for `loanItems` like I mentioned above?

Comment: Yeah I did set it.

Comment: Are you able to post the full API response?

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Use software like Postman or SoapUI to make an API request and then include the response in your question.